# Spring AOP, Use only one pointcut when two pointcut match

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-aop, aspect

anyone have an idea of how doing that :

I have two pointcut, one generic and an one specific. The two pointcuts will intercept the same method invocation but I want to just call the specific pointcut.
Someone Have an idea.

Why I want to do that : imagine a spring repository, I want to intercept all find call we a generic pointcut and execute some code to check access. In Some case, I will redefined new find methods with other arguments, access rules. This new queries will be matched automaticaly by the generic pointcut. But I need a different pointcut in that case to match the specific query.

for example I need something like that :

```
@Pointcut("execution(public * *..*Repository.*(..))")
@Pointcut("execution(public * *..*Repository.find*(..))")
```

for all methods of my repository I will use the first pointcut but for all find methods I will use the second one.
I want that the Overloading will be automatic. I have try @Before("pointcut1 && ! pointcut2") but if I want to make a third pointcut I will need to modify the @Before expression.

Thank

Comment: maybe the negation helps here? so you match `find` and all others that are *not* `find` 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2266850/spring-aop-pointcut-syntax-for-and-or-and-not

Comment: Yes the negation work but like I explane I want something more automatics. For each case I will need to negate the specific pointcut to exclude it from the generic. I wan't something more a hierarchical model, execute the most specific first.

Comment: If having separate aspects is an option , you could order the execution of aspects from more specific to generic . Filter out what is not required on the generic aspect through code or an indicator (threadlocal or something) that the method call is already advised ? Do go through [Advice Ordering](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/core.html#aop-ataspectj-advice-ordering)

Comment: I've thinking about this solution. But i've not thinking to save the state on the local thread

Comment: Do go through SO [Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65926489/4214241) . Pure `AspectJ` seems to allow your requirement . With Spring AOP , a thread local variable is what I could come up with

Comment: @R.G is right in everything he said. Just a minor remark about the sample pointcuts used in this question: `**.`  (double asterisk) is not a meaningful part of a type signature. I guess you rather mean `*..` (double dot) instead, e.g. in your case `*..*Repository`. Maybe you want to fix that so as not to confuse other readers.

Answer (score 1):

From Spring reference documentation : [Advice Ordering](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/core.html#aop-ataspectj-advice-ordering)

> When two pieces of advice defined in different aspects both need to run at the same join point, unless you specify otherwise, the order of execution is undefined.

and

> When two pieces of the same type of advice (for example, two @After advice methods) defined in the same @Aspect class both need to run at the same join point, the ordering is undefined

and

> advice methods defined in the same @Aspect class that need to run at the same join point are assigned precedence based on their advice type

If having separate aspects is an option , order the execution of aspects from more specific to generic and throw access exception when a specific access check fails. This would prevent execution of subsequent advises down stream. Another option using Spring AOP is to use a threadlocal variable to mark and identify if a method execution is already advised by a more specific advice.

Do go through the following SO [Question and Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65926489/check-in-spring-aop-if-method-is-called-by-another-annotated-method) which discusses pure AspectJ for greater control on aspect execution.